i want to send XCM message from my own react app
Can anyone help on Xcm Message I want to send message from my parachain. It work when I use Polkadot.js/app.But its not working with my own frontend tool. It says incorrect format. Can anyone tell what's correct format to contract XCM message in react.
This is my Messaage :
const dest = [{
"V2": {
"parents": 1,
"interior": null
},
}];
        const messages = {
            "V2": [



                {
                    "WithdrawAsset": [
                        {
                            "id": {
                                "Concrete": {
                                    "parants": 0,
                                    "interior": null
                                }
                            },
                            "fun": {
                                "Fungible": 1000000000000
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                },



                {
                    "BuyExecution": [
                        {
                            "fees": {
                                "id": {
                                    "Concrete": {
                                        "parants": 0,
                                        "interior": null
                                    }
                                },
                                "fun": {
                                    "Fungible": 1000000000000
                                }
                            },
                            "weightLimit": "Unlimited"
                        }
                    ],
                },


                {
                    "Transact": [
                        {
                            "originType": "Native",
                            "requireWeightAtMost": 40000000000,
                            "call": encodedCallData
                        }
                    ],
                },


                { "RefundSurplus": [], },


                {
                    "DepositAsset": [{
                        "assets": {
                            "Definite": "All"
                        },
                        "maxAssets": 1,
                        "beneficiary": {
                            "parents": 0,
                            "interior": {
                                "X1": {
                                    "Parachain": 2001
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }]
                }




            ]
        };

I am Getting this Error 
